# How to convert accented letters to regular char in Java

Tags: java, char

How do I convert `&#198;` and `&#225;` into a regular English char with Java ? What I have is something like this : Local TV from Paran`&#225;`. How to convert it to [Parana] ?

Comment: This question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet Please refer to that question for an answer

Comment: &#198; corresponds to the char with int value 198.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at icu4j or the JDK 1.6 Normalizer:

```
public String removeAccents(String text) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                     .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

Comment: You probably meant "Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD)" instead of "Normalizer.decompose(text, false, 0)"

Comment: I think I accidentally put in the old sun. class scheme instead. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Normalizer.Form.NFKD may be better than Normalizer.Form.NFD for his purposes, depending on how he wants to treat ligatures. eg: NFKD will transform `"ﬁ"` into `"fi"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3322174/535203 says `replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this automatically -- you'd have to substitute manually using [String.replaceAll](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
String str = "Paraná";
str = str.replaceAll("á", "a");
str = str.replaceAll("Æ", "a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to the following code snippet:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String original = new String("Ramesh Öhrman");
        try {
            
            System.out.println(StringUtils.stripAccents(original));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        
    }
}
```

Output: Ramesh Ohrman