# Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?

Tags: java, string, diacritics

Is there a better way for getting rid of accents and making those letters regular apart from using `String.replaceAll()` method and replacing letters one by one?
Example:

Input:  `orčpžsíáýd`

Output: `orcpzsiayd`

It doesn't need to include all letters with accents like the Russian alphabet or the Chinese one.

Answer (score 458, accepted):

**Use [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) to handle this for you.**

```
string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
// or Normalizer.Form.NFKD for a more "compatible" deconstruction
```

This will separate all of the accent marks from the characters.  Then, you just need to compare each character against being a letter and throw out the ones that aren't.

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

If your text is in unicode, you should use this instead:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");
```

For unicode, `\\P{M}` matches the base glyph and `\\p{M}` (lowercase) matches each accent.

Thanks to GarretWilson for the pointer and [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for the great unicode guide.

Comment: Works well but slow for some needs, see my comment lower for faster solution with some limitations which may not be an issue. For a few normalizations I'd definitely use this answer of course, because it's much cleaner, more general and without the need or your own code.

Comment: This compiles the regular expression each time, which is fine if you only need it once, but if you need to do this with a lot of text, pre-compiling the regex is a win.

Comment: Note that not all Latin-based letters decompose to ASCII+accents. This will kill eg. "Latin {capital,small} letter l with stroke" used in Polish.

Comment: This is a good approach, but removing all non-ASCII characters is overkill and will probably remove things you don't want, as others have indicated. It would be better to remove all Unicode "marks"; including non-spacing marks, spacing/combining marks, and enclosing marks. You can do this with `string.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "")`. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html for more information.

Comment: You probably want to use Normalizer.Form.NFKD rather than NFD - NFKD will convert things like ligatures into ascii characters (eg ﬁ to fi), NFD will not do this.

Comment: @chesterm8, interestingly NFKD is converting "ﬁ" to "fi", but it's not converting "Æ" to "AE". I guess I'll have to bring up the Unicode data to find out why, but it wasn't what I expected.

Comment: @GarretWilson replaceAll("\\p{M}") can only be used with JAVA 8 and on? I was reading on the link http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Anyone that wants a Kotlin extension solution:
 `fun String.normalize(): String = Normalizer.normalize(this, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replace(Regex("\\p{M}"), "")`

Answer (score 206):

As of 2011 you can use Apache Commons [StringUtils.stripAccents(input)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents-java.lang.String-) (since 3.0):

```
    String input = StringUtils.stripAccents("Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ");
    System.out.println(input);
    // Prints "This is a funky String"
```

**Note:**

The accepted answer (Erick Robertson's) doesn't work for Ø or Ł. Apache Commons 3.5 doesn't work for Ø either, but it does work for Ł. After reading the [Wikipedia article for Ø](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98), I'm not sure it should be replaced with "O": it's a separate letter in Norwegian and Danish, alphabetized after "z". It's a good example of the limitations of the "strip accents" approach.

Comment: If you don't want to include the library you can take the two methods involved in that feature easily from source at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: As a Dane, the Danish/Norwegian ø just as the French œ and the German/Swedish/Hungarian/Estonian etc. ö originates as a short way to write oe. So depending on your purpose this may be the substitution you want.

Answer (score 65):

The solution by @virgo47 is very fast, but approximate. The accepted answer uses Normalizer and a regular expression. I wondered what part of the time was taken by Normalizer versus the regular expression, since removing all the non-ASCII characters can be done without a regex:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class Strip {
    public static String flattenToAscii(String string) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.length());
        string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
            if (c <= '\u007F') sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Small additional speed-ups can be obtained by writing into a char[] and not calling toCharArray(), although I'm not sure that the decrease in code clarity merits it:

```
public static String flattenToAscii(String string) {
    char[] out = new char[string.length()];
    string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = string.length(); i < n; ++i) {
        char c = string.charAt(i);
        if (c <= '\u007F') out[j++] = c;
    }
    return new String(out);
}
```

This variation has the advantage of the correctness of the one using Normalizer and some of the speed of the one using a table. On my machine, this one is about 4x faster than the accepted answer, and 6.6x to 7x slower that @virgo47's (the accepted answer is about 26x slower than @virgo47's on my machine).

Comment: `out` must be resized to match the number of valid characters `j` before it is used to construct the string object.

Comment: I have an objection to this solution. Imagine input "æøåá". Current `flattenToAscii` creates result "aa.." where dots represent \u0000. That is not good. First question is - how to represent "unnormalizable" characters? Let's say it will be ?, or we can leave NULL char there, but in any case we have to preserve the correct position of these (just like regex solution does). For this the if in the loop must be something like: `if (c <= '\u007F') out[j++] = c; else if (Character.isLetter(c)) out[j++] = '?';` It will slow it down a bit, but it must be correct in the first place. ;-)

Comment: Ad my last comment (too bad they can't be longer) - maybe positive take (`isLetter`) is not the right one, but I didn't find better. I'm not Unicode expert, so I don't know how to better identify the class of the single character that replaces original character. Letters work OK for most applications/usages.

Comment: Finally, this solution (with fix) does not produce the same output as regex version. That's because regex version leaves this kind of characters (like ø) there as-is. In this sense this answer at least does not leave any non-ascii characters there (which is expected result) even in corner cases like these. So in the end this seems to be the most correct solution. Of course, with my suggested fix applied, so the positions of the letters are correct, whatever the replacement character (?) is going to be.

Comment: You probably want to use Normalizer.Form.NFKD rather than NFD - NFKD will convert things like ligatures into ascii characters (eg ﬁ to fi), NFD will not do this.

Comment: For us we wanted to remove the character altogether.  To ensure there wasn't trailing null characters I removed them with an alternative String constructor:
return new String(out, 0, j);

Answer (score 33):

EDIT: If you're not stuck with Java <6 and speed is not critical and/or translation table is too limiting, use answer by David. The point is to use `Normalizer` (introduced in Java 6) instead of translation table inside the loop.

While this is not "perfect" solution, it works well when you know the range (in our case Latin1,2), worked before Java 6 (not a real issue though) and is much faster than the most suggested version (may or may not be an issue):

```
    /**
 * Mirror of the unicode table from 00c0 to 017f without diacritics.
 */
private static final String tab00c0 = "AAAAAAACEEEEIIII" +
    "DNOOOOO\u00d7\u00d8UUUUYI\u00df" +
    "aaaaaaaceeeeiiii" +
    "\u00f0nooooo\u00f7\u00f8uuuuy\u00fey" +
    "AaAaAaCcCcCcCcDd" +
    "DdEeEeEeEeEeGgGg" +
    "GgGgHhHhIiIiIiIi" +
    "IiJjJjKkkLlLlLlL" +
    "lLlNnNnNnnNnOoOo" +
    "OoOoRrRrRrSsSsSs" +
    "SsTtTtTtUuUuUuUu" +
    "UuUuWwYyYZzZzZzF";

/**
 * Returns string without diacritics - 7 bit approximation.
 *
 * @param source string to convert
 * @return corresponding string without diacritics
 */
public static String removeDiacritic(String source) {
    char[] vysl = new char[source.length()];
    char one;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        one = source.charAt(i);
        if (one >= '\u00c0' && one <= '\u017f') {
            one = tab00c0.charAt((int) one - '\u00c0');
        }
        vysl[i] = one;
    }
    return new String(vysl);
}
```

Tests on my HW with 32bit JDK show that this performs conversion from àèéľšťč89FDČ to aeelstc89FDC 1 million times in ~100ms while Normalizer way makes it in 3.7s (37x slower). In case your needs are around performance and you know the input range, this may be for you.

Enjoy :-)

Comment: A lot of the slowness of the suggested version is due to the regular expression, not the Normalizer. Using Normalizer but removing the non-ASCII characters 'by hand' is faster, although still not as fast as your version. But it works for all of Unicode instead of just latin1 and latin2.

Comment: I expanded this to work with more characters, http://pastebin.com/FAAm6a2j, Note it won't work correctly with multichar characters such as Ǆ (DZ). It will only produce 1 character from it. Also my function uses char instead of strings, which is quicker IF you're handling char anyways, so you dont have to convert.

Comment: Hey I don't understand what are those letters on tab00c0 field stand for? for example "AAAAAAACEEEEIIII" or "lLlNnNnNnnNnOoOo" etc. Never seen them before. Where did you find them? Also Why don't you just use the coresponding codes?

Comment: @ThanosF just try to go through the code (with debugger if needed). What this does is for every character in a string: "Is this character between \u00c0 and \u017f? If so, replace it with 7bit ASCII character from the table." Table just covers two encoding pages (Latin 1 and 2) with their 7bit equivalents. So if it's character with code \u00e0 (à) it will take its 7bit approximation from 32nd position of the table (e0-c0=32) - that is "a". Some characters are not letters, those are left there with their code.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Where can I find those encoding pages so that I can extend this Variable to my language? (Greek) Accepted answer already does the job replacing greek accented letters but I wanted to try your method too and run some benchmarks :)

Comment: @ThanosF If you google Unicode table you'll find the table - better yet though go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Greek_in_Unicode and read that. It seems that you have two tables to cover that are rather far away from each other. You may create one big table - it would ~8k of characters. That's not the problem, but then you'd potentially replace chars you don't want to define, unless you'd agree on some "don't replace char" (space would be convenient). Only if it's not a space you'd assign it to "one" variable. Or add more ifs with different tables and offsets. :-)

Comment: thanks! The second table is ancient Greek that it's not used in every day life so I won't need this

Comment: This solution does not convert char "Ệệ" into "Ee".

Comment: @thuanle Are these in Latin 1 or 2? It seems these are U+1ec6/7, which is way beyond the range of my solution. So yes, it does not support these and I clearly state so in the answer.

Comment: @virgo47 thanks for answer. 
It was 0x1EFF, in the range 0x1E00 - 0x1EFF : Latin Extended Additional.

So, can we make any modification to make this work with Latin Extended Addtional?

Comment: @thuanle You need to define another table and add another if block (3 lines), that should do it. There are probably more sophisticated ways how to design it, but this should cover another continuous section of characters. I leave that exercise to those who need it, of course. :-)

Answer (score 28):

```
System.out.println(Normalizer.normalize("àèé", Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""));
```

worked for me. The output of the snippet above gives "aee" which is what I wanted, but

```
System.out.println(Normalizer.normalize("àèé", Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""));
```

didn't do any substitution.

Comment: Confirming this... normally ASCII works just fine, but I encountered this problem on Linux (64b) with JRockit (1.6.0_29 64b). Can't confirm it with any other setup, can't confirm that corellation, but I *can* confirm that the other suggested solution worked and for that I vote this one up. :-) (BTW: It did some replacement, but not enough, it changed Ú to U for instance, but not á to a.)

Comment: You probably want to use Normalizer.Form.NFKD rather than NFD - NFKD will convert things like ligatures into ascii characters (eg ﬁ to fi), NFD will not do this.

Comment: @KarolS I don't see either of them containing any [accents](https://emw3.com/unicode-accents.html)

Comment: @eis A slash across a letter counts as a diacritic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic
And if you go by a stricter definition of an "accent" as on that Wikipedia page, then diaeresis is not an accent, so Nico's answer is still wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the language, those might not be considered accents (which change the sound of the letter), but diacritical marks

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic#Languages_with_letters_containing_diacritics

"Bosnian and Croatian have the symbols č, ć, đ, š and ž, which are considered separate letters and are listed as such in dictionaries and other contexts in which words are listed according to alphabetical order."

Removing them might be inherently changing the meaning of the word, or changing the letters into completely different ones.

Comment: Agreed. For example in swedish: "höra" (hear) -> "hora" (whore)

Comment: It doesn't matter what they mean.  The question is how to remove them.

Comment: Erick: It matters what they're called. If the question asks how to remove accents, and if those aren't accents, then the answer may not be just how to remove all of those things that look like accents. Though this should probably be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I think the normal use case for this is search, particularly search of mixed languages, often with an English keyboard as input, in which case it's better to get false positives than false negatives.

Comment: @Smig Whether it matters or not what they're called, Erick is right, it's not relevant as an answer whatsoever since it doesn't even attempt to address the question asked. Should be a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue related to Strings equality check, One of the comparing string has 
[ASCII character code 128-255](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

> i.e., Non-breaking space - [Hex - A0] Space [Hex - 20].
>   To show Non-breaking space over HTML. I have used the following [**`spacing entities`**](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/html-sentences.html). Their character and its bytes are like *`&emsp is very wide space[ ]{-30, -128, -125}, &ensp is somewhat wide space[ ]{-30, -128, -126}, &thinsp is narrow space[ ]{32} , Non HTML Space {}`*
>
> ```
> String s1 = "My Sample Space Data", s2 = "My Sample Space Data";
> System.out.format("S1: %s\n", java.util.Arrays.toString(s1.getBytes()));
> System.out.format("S2: %s\n", java.util.Arrays.toString(s2.getBytes()));
> ```
>
> Output in Bytes:
>
> *S1: [77, 121, `32`, 83, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, `32`, 83, 112, 97, 99, 101, `32`, 68, 97, 116, 97]*
>   *S2: [77, 121, `-30, -128, -125`, 83, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, `-30, -128, -125`, 83, 112, 97, 99, 101, `-30, -128, -125`, 68, 97, 116, 97]*

Use below code for Different Spaces and their Byte-Codes: [`wiki for List_of_Unicode_characters`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

```
String spacing_entities = "very wide space,narrow space,regular space,invisible separator";
System.out.println("Space String :"+ spacing_entities);
byte[] byteArray = 
    // spacing_entities.getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8") );
    // Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode( s2 ).array();
    {-30, -128, -125, 44, -30, -128, -126, 44, 32, 44, -62, -96};
System.out.println("Bytes:"+ Arrays.toString( byteArray ) );
try {
    System.out.format("Bytes to String[%S] \n ", new String(byteArray, "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- ➩ ASCII transliterations of Unicode string for Java. [**`unidecode`**](https://github.com/xuender/unidecode)

  ```
  String initials = Unidecode.decode( s2 );
  ```
- ➩ using [`Guava`](https://github.com/google/guava): Google Core [`Libraries for Java`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/19.0).

  ```
  String replaceFrom = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.replaceFrom( s2, " " );
  ```

  *For URL encode [for the space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31595036/5081877) use Guava laibrary.*

  ```
  String encodedString = UrlEscapers.urlFragmentEscaper().escape(inputString);
  ```
- ➩ To overcome this problem used `String.replaceAll()` with some [`RegularExpression`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

  ```
  // \p{Z} or \p{Separator}: any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.
  s2 = s2.replaceAll("\\p{Zs}", " ");


  s2 = s2.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", " ");
  s2 = s2.replaceAll(" ", " ");
  ```
- ➩ Using [java.text.Normalizer.Form](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html).
  This enum provides constants of the four Unicode normalization forms that are described in [Unicode Standard Annex #15](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-23.html) — Unicode Normalization Forms and two methods to access them.

  [image]

  ```
  s2 = Normalizer.normalize(s2, Normalizer.Form.NFKC);
  ```

---

Testing String and outputs on different approaches like ➩ Unidecode, Normalizer, [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents(java.lang.String)).

```
String strUni = "Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ Æ,Ø,Ð,ß";

// This is a funky String AE,O,D,ss
String initials = Unidecode.decode( strUni );

// Following Produce this o/p: Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ Æ,Ø,Ð,ß
String temp = Normalizer.normalize(strUni, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
temp = pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll("");

String input = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents( strUni );
```

---

Using **Unidecode** is the [`best choice`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43370834/5081877), My final Code shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "My Sample Space Data", s2 = "My Sample Space Data";
    String initials = Unidecode.decode( s2 );
    if( s1.equals(s2)) { //[ , ] %A0 - %2C - %20 « http://www.ascii-code.com/
        System.out.println("Equal Unicode Strings");
    } else if( s1.equals( initials ) ) {
        System.out.println("Equal Non Unicode Strings");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Equal");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [Junidecode](https://github.com/gcardone/junidecode) . It will handle not only 'Ł' and 'Ø', but it also works well for transcribing from other alphabets, such as Chinese, into Latin alphabet.

Comment: Looks promising, but I wish this was a more active/maintained project and available on Maven.

Comment: Thanks @OlgaMaciaszek for sharing this great library

Comment: @Phil it's available in maven as well https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.gcardone.junidecode/junidecode/0.4.1/jar

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek How do I include or import this library into Talend/Java?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek The way you import this library into a Talend job is via the `tLibraryLoad` component.  After you connect it to a `tJava` component, adding the following line in the advanced settings `import static net.gcardone.junidecode.Junidecode.*;`.  From there, you can invoke the method to transliterate your string.

Answer (score 4):

Since this solution is already available in [StringUtils.stripAccents()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html) at [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3) and working for Ł as mentioned by @DavidS.
But I need this to be working for both Ø and Ł So modified as below. May be help full for others too.

### Update

---

This is modified version of [StringUtils.stripAccents(String obj)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html), that contains old functionality along with handling both Ø and Ł chars.

```
public static String stripAccents(final String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder decomposed = new StringBuilder(Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD));
    for (int i = 0; i < decomposed.length(); i++) {
        if (decomposed.charAt(i) == '\u0141') {
            decomposed.setCharAt(i, 'L');
        } else if (decomposed.charAt(i) == '\u0142') {
            decomposed.setCharAt(i, 'l');
        }else if (decomposed.charAt(i) == '\u00D8') {
            decomposed.setCharAt(i, 'O');
        }else if (decomposed.charAt(i) == '\u00F8') {
            decomposed.setCharAt(i, 'o');
        }
    }
    // Note that this doesn't correctly remove ligatures...
    return Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+").matcher(decomposed).replaceAll("");
}
```

Input string `Ł Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ Ø ø` 
output string `L This is a funky String O o`

Comment: I am getting ̊� TÄ¥Ã¯Å� Ä©Å¡ Ã¢ fÅ¯ÅˆÄ·Å· Å Å¥Å•Ä­Å„Ä¡ Ã˜ Ã¸ as an output

Comment: not sure what input data you applied, may be Normalizer.Form.NFC, NFKC, NFKD you can also try: like  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html#NFC

Comment: I applied same input Ł Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ Ø ø

Answer (score 3):

One of the best way **using regex and Normalizer** if you have no library is :

```
    public String flattenToAscii(String s) {
                if(s == null || s.trim().length() == 0)
                        return "";
                return Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[\u0300-\u036F]", "");
}
```

This is more efficient than replaceAll("[^\p{ASCII}]", "")) and **if you don't need diacritics** (just like your example).

Otherwise, you have to use the p{ASCII} pattern.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

@David Conrad solution is the fastest I tried using the Normalizer, but it does have a bug. It basically strips characters which are not accents, for example Chinese characters and other letters like æ, are all stripped.
The characters that we want to strip are non spacing marks, characters which don't take up extra width in the final string. These zero width characters basically end up combined in some other character. If you can see them isolated as a character, for example like this `, my guess is that it's combined with the space character.

```
public static String flattenToAscii(String string) {
    char[] out = new char[string.length()];
    String norm = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = norm.length(); i < n; ++i) {
        char c = norm.charAt(i);
        int type = Character.getType(c);

        //Log.d(TAG,""+c);
        //by Ricardo, modified the character check for accents, ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5697575/689223
        if (type != Character.NON_SPACING_MARK){
            out[j] = c;
            j++;
        }
    }
    //Log.d(TAG,"normalized string:"+norm+"/"+new String(out));
    return new String(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is converting each char to HEX and replace it with another HEX. It's because there are 2 Unicode typing:

```
Composite Unicode
Precomposed Unicode
```

For example "Ồ" written by Composite Unicode is different from "Ồ" written by Precomposed Unicode. You can copy my sample chars and convert them to see the difference.

```
In Composite Unicode, "Ồ" is combined from 2 char: Ô (U+00d4) and ̀ (U+0300)
In Precomposed Unicode, "Ồ" is single char (U+1ED2)
```

I have developed this feature for some banks to convert the info before sending it to core-bank (usually don't support Unicode) and faced this issue when the end-users use multiple Unicode typing to input the data. So I think, converting to HEX and replace it is the most reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

A fast and safer way

```
public static String removeDiacritics(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return null;
    if (str.isEmpty())
        return "";
    
    int len = str.length();
    StringBuilder sb
        = new StringBuilder(len);
    
    //iterate string codepoints
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ) {
        int codePoint = str.codePointAt(i);
        int charCount
            = Character.charCount(codePoint);
        
        if (charCount > 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < charCount; j++)
                sb.append(str.charAt(i + j));
            i += charCount;
            continue;
        }
        else if (codePoint <= 127) {
            sb.append((char)codePoint);
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        
        sb.append(
            java.text.Normalizer
                .normalize(
                    Character.toString((char)codePoint),
                    java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                        .charAt(0));
        i++;
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, here's solution using Kotlin extension

```
   val String.stripAccents: String
    get() = Regex("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+")
        .replace(
            Normalizer.normalize(this, Normalizer.Form.NFD),
            ""
        )
```

usage

```
val textWithoutAccents = "some accented string".stripAccents
```

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone is strugling to do this in kotlin, this code works like a charm. To avoid inconsistencies I also use .toUpperCase and Trim(). then i cast this function:

```
   fun stripAccents(s: String):String{

   if (s == null) {
      return "";
   }

val chars: CharArray = s.toCharArray()

var sb = StringBuilder(s)
var cont: Int = 0

while (chars.size > cont) {
    var c: kotlin.Char
    c = chars[cont]
    var c2:String = c.toString()
   //these are my needs, in case you need to convert other accents just Add new entries aqui
    c2 = c2.replace("Ã", "A")
    c2 = c2.replace("Õ", "O")
    c2 = c2.replace("Ç", "C")
    c2 = c2.replace("Á", "A")
    c2 = c2.replace("Ó", "O")
    c2 = c2.replace("Ê", "E")
    c2 = c2.replace("É", "E")
    c2 = c2.replace("Ú", "U")

    c = c2.single()
    sb.setCharAt(cont, c)
    cont++

}

return sb.toString()
```

}

to use these fun cast the code like this:

```
     var str: String
     str = editText.text.toString() //get the text from EditText
     str = str.toUpperCase().trim()

     str = stripAccents(str) //call the function
```