# Java change áéőűú to aeouu

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Remove diacritical marks (ń ǹ ň ñ ṅ ņ ṇ ṋ ṉ ̈ ɲ ƞ ᶇ ɳ ȵ) from Unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n---n------------n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from)
>   [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/java-getting-rid-of-accents-and-converting-them-to-regular-letters)

How can i do this? Thanks for the help

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from

Comment: the question is closed, ask a new question

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I think your question is the same as these:

- [Java - getting rid of accents and converting them to regular letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/java-getting-rid-of-accents-and-converting-them-to-regular-letters)
- [Converting Java String to ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707977/converting-java-string-to-ascii)

and hence the answer is also the same:

```
String convertedString = 
       Normalizer
           .normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
           .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

See

- [JavaDoc: Normalizer.normalize(String, Normalizer.Form)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html#normalize%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.text.Normalizer.Form%29)
- [JavaDoc: Normalizer.Form.NFD](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html#NFD)
- [Sun Java Tutorial: Normalizer's API)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html)

**Example Code:**

```
final String input = "Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ";
System.out.println(
    Normalizer
        .normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")
);
```

**Output:**

> This is a funky String

Comment: fortunately I just had to copy and paste it from a previous question (including the first paragraph) :-)

Comment: Sorry but its in Android, not only java, the normalizer class is not in android systems

Comment: OK, then maybe you should ask it again in a separate question, this time mentioning that you are talking about android.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the *Normalizer* class is part of the Android SDK since API 9.

Comment: Funnily Google seems to prefer the duplicates in search results, always.

Comment: That´s a great answer, but need java 6 :(

Comment: @Deoxyseia true, but Java 6 has been around for 10 years, and even Java 7 has been deprecated years ago. Time to upgrade? :-)

Comment: For the solution proposed, the output for "øóöë" is "ooe", and should be "oooe"

Answer (score 12):

You can use `java.text.Normalizer` to separate base letters and diacritics, then remove the latter via a regexp:

```
public static String stripDiacriticas(String s) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(s, Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

Comment: I used something similar that did the job: Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+").matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");

Answer (score 10):

First - you shouldn't. These symbols carry special phonetic properties which should not be ignored.

The way to convert them is to create a `Map` that holds each pair:

```
Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
map.put('á', 'a');
map.put('é', 'e');
//etc..
```

and then loop the chars in the string, creating a new string by calling `map.get(currentChar)`

Comment: +1 for *you shouldn't*

Comment: another +1 for *shouldn't*. A replacement for 'ä' in german language would be "ae" (surprise: two chars...) and I bet there a lot more examples for other spoken languages.

Comment: @Andreas true, I guess that would call for a locale-specific Normalizer function (good luck with that :-)).

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why you would to this. e.g. if you wanna store a file on disc but the filename contains these characters. NTFS (as most other FS) wont allow that.

Comment: Are you sure? I haven't had problems with special-symbol file names recently

Comment: @Bozho are you sure? Or in other words, have you tried every possible unicode character on all filesystems java supports? I wouldn´t take the risk...

Comment: I think I wanted this for sorting a string collection.

Comment: Another use case (though probably ultimately futile): detecting profanity filter dodging.

Comment: If you want to put them in a decently looking url then you should.

Comment: always ignore diacritics in search fields. Users get annoyed when they have to type a special character otherwise they can't find what they want.