# How to get an alphanumeric String from any string in Java?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ń ǹ ň ñ ṅ ņ ṇ ṋ ṉ ̈ ɲ ƞ ᶇ ɳ ȵ --> n or Remove diacritical marks from unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-cha)
>   [How to replace special characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283351/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string)

I would like to format some String such as `"I>Télé"` to something like `"itele"`.
The idea is that I want my String to be lower case (done), without whitespaces (done), no accents or special characters (like `>`, `<`, `/`, `%`, `~`, `é`, `@`, `ï` etc).

It is okay to delete occurences of special characters, but I want to keep letters while removing accents (as I did in my example). Here is what I did, but I don't think that the good solution is to replace every é,è,ê,ë by "e", than do it again for "i","a" etc, and then remove every special character...

```
String name ="I>télé" //example
String result = name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "").replace("é","e").........;
```

The purpose of that is to provide a valid filename for resources for an Android app, so if you have any other idea, I'll take it !

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453284/1343161) answer can help you?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [`java.text.Normalizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class to convert your text into normal Latin characters followed by diacritic marks (accents), where possible.  So for example, the single-character string `"é"` would become the two character string `['e', {COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}]`.

After you've done this, your String would be a combination of unaccented characters, accent modifiers, and the other special characters you've mentioned.  At this point you could filter the characters in your string using only a whitelist to keep what you want (which could be as simple as `[A-Za-z0-9]` for a regex, depending on what you're after).

An approach might look like:

```
String name ="I>télé"; //example
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(name, Form.NFD);
String result = normalized.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks to the links provided, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4122207/1520739). And The solution would be a combination of this and replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""). Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for thinking at Normalizer

Comment: Thank you very much. This saved me a lot of time and ugly regex!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
String res = ""
for (char c : name.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLetter(c) ||Character.isDigit(c))
        res += c    
}

//Normalize using the method below
```

http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2009/10/how-to-strip-accents-from-strings-using-java-6/

```
public static String stripAccents(String s) {    
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);   
    s = s.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""); 
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using ascii code. [may this link will help](http://www.asciitable.com/)