# How can I convert a unicode character in XML to an equivalent ASCII character in IBM message broker or IIB10?

Tags: unicode, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am working on IIB10 right now, and we have a problem with candidate's names sometimes which contain accented/Unicode characters which need to be replaced with its equivalent ASCII character either in ESQL or Java. The input parser in XMLNC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122170/java-change-%C3%A1%C3%A9%C5%91%C5%B1%C3%BA-to-aeouu

Comment: Great thanks Joop  :), i'll try this and come back