# COLLATE function in Realm Android

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, android-database

I am working on realm Database in one of my projects. I want to implement **COLLATE** function(SQL) in one of my realm queries. Is there any way I can add that.

My Realm Query:

```
ArrayList<FolderTable> = (ArrayList<FolderTable>) realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(FolderTable.class).equalTo("folderType", "ICD10").and().equalTo("isFolderDeleted", "false").sort("folderName").findAll());
```

Reference SQL query:

```
select _id, folderName from folderTable where folderType="ICD10" and  isFolderDeleted="false" order by folderName COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```

Comment: sorting case insensitively is not supported in realm
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2291

Comment: I just stored an additional field that had all accents removed and queried on top of that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4122200/2413303