# How to remove special char from spanish word

Tags: java, string

```
String s = "VIRÚ";
```

In my string `s` I have a special charecter, this is a spanish charecter and I want to remove this and all spanish special charecter from my string. How can I remove.

Expected output

```
VIRU
```

Comment: what the expected output?

Comment: my expected out put is VIRU

Comment: take a look at this please [Java change áéőűú to aeouu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122170/java-change-%C3%A1%C3%A9%C5%91%C5%B1%C3%BA-to-aeouu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`StringUtils.stripAccents`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents-java.lang.String-) of Apache Commons:

```
String output = StringUtils.stripAccents("VIRÚ"); 
System.out.println(output); // VIRU
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It seems good but that method is not found here `The method stripAccents(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils` import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

Comment: @user9130953 I'm not sure which `StringUtils` you are working with. If you are using Maven, you can add this.

Comment: @user9130953 This method is only available in commons lang3 - you're probably using an old (2.x) version where the method isn't available.