# Java - Converting a German accented characters to two letter equivalents

Tags: java, android, string

I need to convert a string containing accented German letters to their two letter equivalents as follows:

ae = ä | oe = ö | ue = ü | sz = ß

How can I do this in Java? I see their are other questions where the accents are simply removed, but I can't figure out how to change it to do what I want. I'm completely new to Java, so don't even know how to start approaching this.

[Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/java-getting-rid-of-accents-and-converting-them-to-regular-letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String a="wörd";
String b=a.replaceAll("ö", "oe");
System.out.println(b);
```

This will print *woerd* . you can concatenate replaces

```
 String a="wördsämple";
String b=a.replaceAll("ö", "oe").replaceAll("ä","ae");
System.out.println(b);
```

This will print *woerdsaemple*, and so on...