# replace many single characters with one char in java?

Tags: java, replace

In PHP, I can do:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(à|á|ạ|ả|ã|â|ầ|ấ|ậ|ẩ|ẫ|ă|ằ|ắ|ặ|ẳ|ẵ)/", 'a', $str);
```

means that in a string that contains any char like **à, á, a, ả**, ......will be replace by **a**.

How can I do the equivalence in Java?

Comment: Please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/java-getting-rid-of-accents-and-converting-them-to-regular-letters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to use [a much more generic solution](http://www.drillio.com/en/software-development/java/removing-accents-diacritics-in-any-language/) for this problem:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;

// ...

public static String removeAccents(String text) {
    return text == null ? null
        : Normalizer.normalize(text, Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

This removes all diacritical marks, from any letter, in any script.

Comment: When I try to run this code my compiler says change encoding or remove  the characters which are not supported. How to make it work?

Comment: It means that your source file contains characters the compiler doesn't understand. I can't tell what's going on without seeing the whole source file.

Answer (score 3):

Something very similar:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("[àáạảãâầấậẩẫăằắặẳẵ]","a");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replace("Your character sequence" , "a");
```