# Java ignore special characters in string matching

Tags: java, string, compare, special-characters

I want to match two strings in java eg.

text: `János`

searchExpression: `Janos`

Since I don't want to replace all special characters, I thought I could just make the `á` a wildcard, so everything would match for this character. For instance if I search in `János` with `Jxnos`, it should find it. Of course there could be multiple special characters in the text. Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this via any pattern matcher, or do I have to compare char by char?

Comment: Please read about a possible approach based on normalizing your string eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette - this approach would make it very easy to remove the special chars

Comment: Thanks for that information, I didn't think about using the apache.commons library. The stripAccents does exactly what I need. If you would write your comment as anwer, I could accept it.

Comment: done - glad this worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to strip the accent with the help of Apache Commons [StringUtils.stripAccents](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)(input) method:

```
String input = StringUtils.stripAccents("János");
System.out.println(input); //Janos
```

Make sure to also read upon the more elaborate approaches based on the `Normalizer` class: [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette)

Answer (score 2):

use pattern and matcher classes with `J\\Snos` as regex. `\\S` matches any non-space character.

```
String str = "foo János bar Jxnos";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("J\\Snos").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
János
Jxnos
```

Comment: why not a `.` instead of `\\S`?

Comment: because i think op don't want to allow a space character in-between.