# String conversion doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to capitalize and normalize unicode characters on a String, but none of the methods work as expected.
Here is the related code:

```
String in = input.getText().toString();
            in.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(in);
            in= Normalizer.normalize(in,Normalizer.Form.NFC);
            System.out.println(in);
            stripOut.setText(in);
```

First the "toUpperCase()" method doesn't do nothing.
Second the "Normalize" method doesn't remove the accents but move them to the next character.
Input-Output examples:

```
Input: φάε ήλιο δεν ξέρεις
UpperCase.out﹕ φάε ήλιο δεν ξέρεις
Normalize.out φάε ήλιο δεν ξέρεις

Input: Βέλγιο φορά δρόμους γιατί
UpperCase.out: Βέλγιο φορά δρόμους γιατί
Normalize.out: Βέλγιο φορά δρόμους γιατί
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try in = in.toUpperCase();

Comment: try in=in.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());

Comment: It was so simple? It works! Thanks, a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First the "toUpperCase()" method doesn't do nothing.

Java Strings are immutable and you are not capturing the new uppercase string returned by the method.

> Second the "Normalize" method doesn't remove the accents but move them to the next character.

Normalization does not remove accents. It just just ensures unicode characters are represented in a consistent way.

To remove accents, normalize to the decomposed NFD form and remove non-letter characters. See [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette)

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable in java. You cannot change it " in" value by calling

> "in.toUpperCase();"

If you want to do that, you can do by

```
 in= in.toUpperCase();
```