# Java String. Replace list of chars by other chars list

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have String variable with value- f.e.:
`this is test-str-ing_łóśżćń`.

And I would like replace this chars:

, `-`, `ł`,`ó`,`ś`,`ż`,`ć`,`ń`
with those:

`_`,`_`,`l`,`o`,`s`,`z`,`c`,`n`.

And I mean here, that if parser will found f.e.: char `-` (which is second in first list) should be replaced with char that is in the same position/place in second list, which in this example is: `_`.

The char `ó` should be replaced with char `o`.

The char `ń` should be replaced with char `n`.

In my case the list of characters to replace is quite long and parsing in loop for each char to replace would not be enought efficient.

I know method `replaceAll()`. but it only accept one in String and one out String

So I am looking for method, that will allow me to work on arrays/list of Strings instead of single String.

Please give me some help.

Comment: I suggest you give a shot at apache commons lang & `StringUtils` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: replaceAll is heavy weight (regex). fast is replace() with few variants.

Comment: professional seems implement "codepage" operations with CharsetProvider and family. I saw something for ancient polish pages 852, mazovia and converters.

Comment: Are you trying to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3322152/335858)?

Comment: Have a look at the question linked by dasblinkenlight. I have the strong feeling that that's what you're after. Add a second call to  `replaceAll` and replace spaces, minuses etc. with an underscore.

Comment: `replaceAll()` when lighter alternative exist is overkilling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `java.text.Normalizer` to Decompose accented letters in base letter plus "combining diacritical marks."

```
String base = Normalizer.normalize(accented, Form.NFKD)
    .replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");
```

This does a decompose (D) normalization, and then removes Marks.

Some replacements still needed.

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try, cause seems to be most elegant proposition.

Comment: Tested. It doesn't convert `ł` to `l`, and still need to change `space` to `_`

Comment: I've added some extra `replaceAll` to achieve my goal: `return Normalizer.normalize(stringToConvert,Form.NFKD).replaceAll("\\p{M}", "").replaceAll(" ", "_").replaceAll("ł", "l");`. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: It would suffice to do `.replace("ł", "l")` maybe even `.replace(' ', '_')` without the regex overhead.

Comment: The string replace is faster than regex replace and the char replace is faster than string replace since the new string length is known ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

```
    char[] out = new char[src.length()];
    for( j ...){
    inputChar = src.charAt(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < convertChars.length; i++) {
       if (inputChar == convertChars[i]) {
         inputChar = toChars[i];
       }
     }
    }
     out[j] = inputChar ;
   }
    out2 = new String(out);
```

Extracted from bigger code without IDE, not tested. Loop (I hope) don't allocate objects and should not degrade speed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a static lookup table:

```
private static char[] substitutions = new char[65536];
static {
    // Initialize
    for (char c = 0; c < substitutions.length; c++) {
        substitutions[c] = c;
    }
    // Now add mappings.
    substitions['-'] = '_'; // Map source->target character
    ... // Add the rest
}
// LATER IN Code
char[] stringChars = inputString.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.length; i++) {
    stringChars[i] = substitutions[stringChars[i]];
}
outputString = new String(stringChars);
```

Comment: Probably on of the fastest algorithms (what with RAM? maybe isn't problem?) I had used this technique extensively in "C", DOS times, `substitutions ` equivalent had 256B, highly optimizing C compiler does basic operation in 2-3 CPU cycles.

Comment: That array is 128kb which is nothing on today's machines.