# Converting String which contains Turkish characters to lowercase

Tags: java, string, lowercase

I want to convert a string which contains Turkish characters to lowercase with Turkish characters mapped into English equivalents i.e. `"İĞŞÇ"` -> `"igsc"`.

When I use `toLowerCase(new Locale("en", "US"))` function it converts for example `İ` to `i` but with dotted.

How can I solve this problem? (I'm using Java 7)

Thank you.

Comment: Does this help: http://grepalex.com/2013/02/14/java-7-and-the-dotted--and-dotless-i/ ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may

1) First, remove the accents :

the following comes from this topic :

[Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette) :

> Use java.text.Normalizer to handle this for you.

```
string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

> This will separate all of the accent marks from the characters. Then,
>   you just need to compare each character against being a letter and
>   throw out the ones that aren't.

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

> If your text is in unicode, you should use this instead:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");
```

> For unicode, \P{M} matches the base glyph and \p{M} (lowercase)
>   matches each accent.

2) Then, just put the remaining `String` to lower case

```
string = string.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String testString = "İĞŞÇ";
System.out.println(testString);
Locale trlocale = new Locale("tr-TR");
testString = testString .toLowerCase(trlocale);
System.out.println(testString);
```

Works like a charm :)

Comment: The least I can say is that your solution is... not universal.
When I try it, I get "iğşç", while the OP asked for "igsc"...