# Higher lowercase - how to make it equal?

Tags: android, search, textview

I have a textView in which I can search some words and the code for the search is this:

```
public void btn_search(View view) {
    int total = 0;
    String word_search = Etxt.getText().toString().trim();
    String fullTxt = textView.getText().toString();
    String[] array = fullTxt.split("\n");
    String word;
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        word = array[i];
        if (word.contains(word_search)) {
            st.append("<b><i>" + word.trim() + "</i></b>");
            total++;
        } else {
            st.append(word);
        }
        st.append("<br>");
    }
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + st));
    text_total.setText("Ergebnisse: " + total);
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I search something, I must pay attention to the higher lower case. And the question is: How can I make the higher lower case equal, so that I can search something without paying attention to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `toLowerCase()` to make `contains` case sensitive

```
  word = array[i].toLowerCase();
     if (word.contains(word_search.toLowerCase())) {
```

To `append` the original use

```
    int total = 0;
    String word_search = Etxt.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    //                                                     ^^^ 
    String fullTxt = textView.getText().toString();
    String[] array = fullTxt.split("\n");
    String word;
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        word = array[i];
        if (word.toLowerCase().contains(word_search)) {
            //   ^^^^ won't change the original case , to append later 
            // toLowerCase() returns the new string object in lower case
            // so original "word" string object stays the same 
            st.append("<b><i>" + word.trim() + "</i></b>");
            total++;
        } else {
            st.append(word);
        }
        st.append("<br>");
    }
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + st));
    text_total.setText("Ergebnisse: " + total);
```

Comment: @android try the updated answer , i had that in mind so see the example code

Comment: @android thanks for compliment , i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Comment: I have another question. It's almost the same I think. But how can I make this with accented letters? Thanks for answer! :)

Comment: @android It suppose to have no issue , `À` will be converted to `à` using `toLowerCase` function

Comment: I know. I asked the question wrong. I mean that À will be converted to A or a. Can you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: @android that would be wrong , `À` will be converted to `à` not to `A` or `a`  but if you want to convert accented chars to english alphabets then you have to do it manually , you can use [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette)