# How to ignore accent sensitive in java.sql.Statement.executeQuery()

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I'm using `ResultSet java.sql.Statement.executeQuery(String sql) throws SQLException`

When I call this method, it is accent sensitive. How can I ignore this ?

```
String nom = "Labbe";// i want to find here "Labbe" and "Labbé" !
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from Personne P Where P.nom = "+ nom);
```

Comment: you want to ignore *what*? Show your actual code please.

Comment: I added the code above, so i want to ignore the accent sensitive; like Labbé and Labbe.

Comment: by storing the phrase you are going to search for in lower case and without accents in the database in the first place.

Comment: yes but i want to a way to find in the database the name "Labbé" and "Labbe" both of them. In my case, i get just "Labbe" (without accent). How can i get the two results ?

Comment: Sorry, the problem i have is not the "case sensitive", but the "accent sensitive"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette)

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @gengisdave, no it is not the same subject, in my case i want to do that in the database query, (but thank you for the link)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I'm using H2 database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to precede the statement with a PRIMARY strength for FRENCH or maybe ENGLISH.

```
SET COLLATION FRENCH STRENGTH PRIMARY;
```

See [set collation](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_collation). This will also help for list ordering, when not defined on the database schema.