# How to strip accents in JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpa-criteria

I'm using JPA Criteria API, and I want to select occurrences where I have a column data like a given string, this is how I do it in SQL :

```
 lower(CONVERT(myTable.lib, 'US7ASCII')) like lower('%'+myString+'%')
```

For example I have a row where `myTable.Lib = 'métier'`, so when the value of `myString` is `'met'` it should select return that row since `CONVERT(myTable.Lib, 'US7ASCII')` in this case will return `'metier'`.

This is how I build my criteria:

```
builder.like(builder.lower(join.get(myTable.lib)),"%" + search.toLowerCase() + "%"));
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette)

Comment: @senape can you please tell me why this question is duplicated ? how can I use `StringUtils.stripAccents` function on a JPA SingularAttribute ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
builder.like(builder.lower(builder.function("convert",String.class,join.get(myTable.lib),builder.literal("US7ASCII"))),"%" + search.toLowerCase() + "%"));
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : `The method function(String, Class<T>, Expression<?>...) in the type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<String>, Path<String>, String)`

Comment: what is `join` ?

Comment: The join variable is of type `Join`

Comment: The third param of the CriteriaBuilder's function method is an Arbitrary Number of Arguments of `Expression` so it's normal that the String param is not applicable for this method,  the 4th param should be like this: `builder.parameter(String.class, "param")` and: `typedQuery.setParameter("param", "US7ASCII");`

Comment: by the way, the code here is using vendor specific function `convert` , thus it wont be portable to DBs not having the same function

Answer (score -1):

The method `CONVERT(..., ...)` is not ANSI SQL standard syntax, but it's ODBC, as well as US7ASCII character set [Oracle's doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch2charset.htm)

The standard syntax is `CONVERT(... USING ...)`

The second problem is how database behaves with conversion.

If you run, on an Oracle DB the simple query

```
select CONVERT('àèìòù', 'US7ASCII') from DUAL;
```

you will receive

```
aeiou
```

The same query in MySQL can't be run, because of the missing US7ASCII character set. According to the Oracle's documentation, its standard counterpart is ASCII, but unfortunately the simple query

```
select CONVERT("àèìòù" USING ASCII)
```

returns `null`

Now, given the problems, as I stated before, using functions to search on data is a very bad idea, since it dramatically affects your queries performance.
In my opinion, you should pick the right **collation** for your tables.

The [collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) is the way characters are ordered and compared. Using a european collation, or an utf8 collation for your tables (or columns or database) will ensure that accented characters are sorted and compared just as the non-accented ones and, above all, you won't need any additional function to your search query.

Comment: So lets say that the `search` string is equal to `"mét"` and the value in the database is equal to `'métier'` in this case the `term` string is equal to `"met"` so this will not fetch any data since the value in the database contains an accent, please read my question, I said that I want to strip accents using JPA Criteria API and not in JAVA, I already did my google search before posting this question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Let me think about it, I'll try to be more helpful :)

Comment: What's the database you are using?

Comment: It doesn't matter what database I use, since JPA is a Java specification, the code should work with any database and JPA implementation.

Comment: I was asking, since by default, MySQL ignores diacritics/accents in searches. So if your query is 
`select * from myTable where myCol like %met%` and you have `métier`, `mètier` or `metier`, it will return all of them. Anyway, we need to clarify the purpose of your question. If it's purely academical or it's for real life. Because in the latter case, I strongly discourage you from using functions within queries, as well as "% term %" like queries, since they badly affect db performance. Give us some more info about your problem I'll be happy to help.

Comment: well, as I said, since I'm using JPA it means that whatever database I use the code should work, in fact, the application I'm working on can be configured to run with any database.

Comment: please, give a review to my answer and let me know what you think