# Regex accent java

Tags: java, string, loops, equals

how do I replace an accent by something else in a string?

I have this :

```
if (personne1.trim().contains("Président"))
```

I have to replace  the `é` by anything (this could be `e`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette

Comment: `.replace("é", "e")`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322174 ( map characters with diacritics to their bases )

Comment: @jhamon: Your linked question isn't actually related exactly to what the OP needs.

Comment: I don't want this to be a replacemet, I want my  word could be "Président" of "President" (if the accent is forgotten)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of XY problem. You don't want to replace only `é` to `e` but also other literals with diacritics. You want to "normalize" the String. Use the [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class:

```
String compared = Normalizer
    .normalize("Président", Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")

if(personne1.trim().contains(compared)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` Class has method called `replace()`.

```
if(personne1.trim().contains("Président")){
   personne1.replace("é", e)
}
```