# Java regex for NonAsciiCharacters

Tags: java, regex, ascii

I'm using this little snippet.

```
string.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]","")
```

I want to delete or remove the nonAsciiCharacters but i have a problem for example the following string is getting rip

```
final String myString = "cada dia es más cercano a Dios.";
```

but the á is getting remove and this is the 225 Ascii character i thought that this regex will replace all the NON-ASCII but á is ascii  character why is this?

Maybe i get it all wrong.

Comment: No, `á` is not an ASCII char, it is an ANSI char.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`á` (a-acute) is not part of ASCII character set. It's a [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE' (U+00E1)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm) character and part of the Latin-1 Supplement UTF-8 block.

You can see it by running:

```
"á".codePoints()
   .mapToObj(Integer::toHexString)
   .forEach(System.out::println); // e1
```

To keep `á` you can either specifically white-list this character in the pattern

```
string.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}á]", "")
```

or white-list a larger group e.g. `p{L}` which contains all letters

Comment: and there is a way to escape all the nonAscii characters but keep the á?  sorry

Comment: @chiperortiz updated answer but the solution will depend on what do you want to do

Comment: you guess it right thanks mate. best regards from venezuela