# How to ignore accents in Spring JPA findBy repository?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, accent-sensitive

Lets say we have this repository:

```
public interface DeviceTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<DeviceType, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DeviceType> {    
    public Iterable<DeviceType> findByNameContaining(String name);    
}
```

How to obtain the same results by ignoring when user mistypes accents ni search filter?

Examples: `João | Joao | JOÃO`, `Marcio | Márcio` etc.

Comment: It is possible to remove the accents from the string, but you would have to have (a version of) the information saved without the accents. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that within Spring's built-in capabilities. You can consider using [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co) to do that, there is an article on this subject [You Have an Accent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html).

Another way is to not store accent letters in DB and perform mapping before executing SQL request or perform mapping on DB side using custom SQL function - but it's a too cumbersome and fragile solution.