# How to simplify (some) Unicode to ASCII?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

Given a unicode string of names like

`"Guns N’ Roses, 2 × 4, Rust in Peace… Polaris, Black No. 1 (Little Miss Scare‐All), À Tout Le Monde"`

where each name contains some non-ASCII character ('’', '×', '…', '‐', 'À'), I am looking for an algorithm that will simplify it to

`"Guns N' Roses, 2 x 4, Rust in Peace... Polaris, Black No. 1 (Little Miss Scare-All), A Tout Le Monde"`

where each non-ASCII character has been replaced by an ASCII substitute.

I know I can handle a whole class of characters (including 'À') by doing

```
Normalizer.normalize(value, Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

and of course, I could trivially handle any other character by using a number of hand-crafted `.replaceAll()`. But I wonder whether there is some standard algorithm that does not require enumerating all remaining characters I want to substitute. Is there even a name for what I want to do?

Comment: While normalization decomposition will allow you to convert `À` to `A`, there is no algorithm that will do the other conversions.  You could try something like parsing [NamesList.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt) and for any non-ASCII character, use its first cross reference which happens to be an ASCII character as a replacement, but [the parsing rules are more complicated than a glance suggests](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.html), and you still wouldn’t have a way to convert the multiplication sign (`×`) to a lowercase `x`.

Comment: It's called transliteration. It can be locale and word dependent. Å could become A or Aa.

Comment: StringUtils#stripAccents() might help here.

Comment: And Ä should become AE if your target language is German. That's the problem with fallback characters; there is no fixed conversion table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a universal solution, [StringUtils.stripAccents](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents-java.lang.String-) rules here. The accented letters won't become digraphs (like *oe* or *ae*), however. Also some non-existing in ASCII but not accented characters, like the German ß have to be handled one by one afterwards, preferably by the chained native `replace()` or `replaceAll()` `String.class` methods.

Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette)

Example:

```
żółtość wszędzie, łatwo wątpić w zieloność ówczesnego świata (Polish); école publique et laïque a fait de la orthographe strictement normalisée, sinon sa principale règle (French); eine große Online-Umfrage in  mittleren Großstädten zeigt, wo Fußgänger und ÖPNV-Nutzer zufrieden sind (German)
```

results in

```
zołtosc wszedzie, łatwo watpic w zielonosc owczesnego swiata (Polish); ecole publique et laique a fait de la orthographe strictement normalisee, sinon sa principale regle (French); eine große Online-Umfrage in  mittleren Großstadten zeigt, wo Fußganger und OPNV-Nutzer zufrieden sind (German)
```