# Talend: get SOUNDEX of String in tMap

Tags: java, mysql, talend, soundex

I am inserting data from a `CSV` file to a `MySQL` database, and one of the columns should contain the `SOUNDEX` representation of a string.

For example, I have the first name as a column in the `CSV` and the database should contain its `SOUNDEX`.

I am using `tMap` between the file delimited and MySQL output, so the operation should be there. Something like SOUNDEX(row1.FIRST_NAME).

Details: Talend Open Studio, MySQL database

Comment: So what do you want? You want us to implement it for you? Are you looking for a library recommendation?

Comment: @StaceyGirl no I am asking how to make it using Talend in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons Codec to do this. First load the library using tLibraryLoad:
[image]

Then use:

```
new org.apache.commons.codec.language.Soundex().encode("<string>")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One question, I faced an error due to a ``Ë`` character in the string. Do you think it's doable?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The character is not mapped: Ë

Comment: I think it's doable, since the vowels are discarded in the soundex algorithm, you can use another Apache Library which can replace Ë with E

Comment: I don't have experience with such libraries. Any recommendations?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/3322152/899863

Comment: Yup ``java.text.Normalizer`` solved it! Thanks again for the help.