# Replace Unicode Characters in a String

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I need to replace diacritic characters (e.g. ä, ó, etc.) with their 'base' character. For most of the characters, this solution works:

```
StringUtils.stripAccents(tmpStr);
```

but this misses four characters: æ, œ, ø, and ß.

I took a look at this solution here [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette). I figured the first solution would work, but it does not.

How can I replace these characters with their 'base' character (e.g. replace æ with a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code says (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html),

```
public static String stripAccents(final String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }        final StringBuilder decomposed = new StringBuilder(Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD));        convertRemainingAccentCharacters(decomposed);        

    // Note that this doesn't correctly remove ligatures...   
 
    return STRIP_ACCENTS_PATTERN.matcher(decomposed).replaceAll(EMPTY);    
}
```

It has a comment that says,
`// Note that this doesn't correctly remove ligatures...`

So may be you need to manually replace those instances.
Something like,

```
    String string = Normalizer.normalize("Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ ß æ œ ø Šťŕĭńġ", Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
    string = string.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");

    string = string.replace("ß", "s");
    string = string.replace("ø", "o");
    string = string.replace("œ", "o");
    string = string.replace("æ", "a");
```

**Diacritical Character to ASCII Character Mapping**
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_chars_mapping.html

Comment: This is what I was leaning towards based on the lack of solutions I was finding. This makes sense.

Comment: It's a good job there aren't so many that it would be intractable to convert them individually ;)