# Java - Replace all accents but retain symbols like Copyright, Trademark and Registered

Tags: java, string, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

```
mystr="MYCOMPANYÂ® PREMIER VISA SIGNATUREÂ® CARD"
```

I tried below ways, but it is not removing the Â.

```
mystr= Normalizer.normalize(mystr, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
mystr= Pattern.compile("\\p{InCOMBINING_DIACRITICAL_MARKS}+").matcher(mystr).replaceAll("");
```

Is there any way to remove the accent characters from above string except the characters like Copyright, Trademark and Registered.

```
expectedString = "MYCOMPANY® PREMIER VISA SIGNATURE® CARD"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette)

Comment: @Abra, above solution is replacing the accent char with a valid letter "A". But I want to remove it completely.

Comment: The trick then would be to replace it with an empty string (`""`)

Comment: I am going to stick my neck out here and say that what you're asking for isn't what you need.  The real problem here looks to a character-set encoding problem.  Almost certainly you have received the string `MYCOMPANY® PREMIER VISA SIGNATURE® CARD` in UTF-8 but have incorrectly decoded it using ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252. In UTF-8, the character `®` is represented by two bytes, but in ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252, the same two bytes represent the characters `Â®`.  Use the correct encoding Instead of fixing up the results of using the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `StringUtils.stripAccents(string);` from Apache Commons Lang.
It removes accents from character but won't delete it, so to get your desired result I've compared the two strings and appended the common characters to a new string.
Download the latest version of binaries from their [website](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) or you can directly download the JAR from this [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/vivzl5i0r1vn6yv/commons-lang3-3.11.jar/file).
Add the JAR libraries through your IDE and import it in code as shown:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String string1 = "MYCOMPANYÂ® PREMIER VISA SIGNATUREÂ® CARD";
        String string2 = StringUtils.stripAccents(string1);
        int n = string1.length();
        char[] arr1 = string1.toCharArray();
        char[] arr2 = string2.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int t = 0; t < n; t++)
            if(arr1[t] == arr2[t]) sb.append(arr2[t]);         
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

It gives the output:

```
MYCOMPANY® PREMIER VISA SIGNATURE® CARD
```