# How to do an ORDER BY ignoring the diacritical marks (use a collation) in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, memgraphdb

I have a list of names where some names contain diacritics characters, like `Á`, `Ê`

For example:

```
Átila
André
Êlisa
Mercês
Sá
```

But when I run a simple query like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
ORDER BY p.Name
```

It returns the names out of alphabetical order, because of the diacritics:

```
André
Mercês
Sá
Átila
Êlisa
```

I would like that it return in alphabetical order, independently of the presence of diacritics (pt-BR / portuguese / Brazil).

I can do this in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Person
ORDER BY Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

How to do that in Cypher?

Comment: I think you'll have to work along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette

Answer (score 1):

Cypher doesn't have the support for specifying `Collation` and `Character Set` as of now, but you can try this for your use case:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p, apoc.text.clean(p.name) AS cleanedName
RETURN p.name
ORDER BY cleanedName
```

[`APOC`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/) is an external library, with some very useful functions.
`apoc.text.clean` is one of them, it only keeps alphanumeric characters in the string and converts them all to lowercase. Hence, there are two limitations, if you want non-alphanumeric characters to play a role in sorting, or the sorting should be case-sensitive, then this is not an exact solution, then you can basically write your own custom procedure and call it from within Cypher, as described [here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template).

Please install the APOC library first, if not already installed.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I'm the co-founder and CTO of Memgraph.

I would say this goes under the proper support for Unicode. [openCypher](https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher) grammar has the support to parse various characters, but it's an implementation detail of how characters are stored and later interpreted. I'm not aware of a clause like `COLLATE` in openCypher.

When it comes to Memgraph, it just stores and interprets raw bytes (for now), which results in the wrong sorting order. Options when using Memgraph are:

- implementing a [user-defined function in C/C++/Python/Rust](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/functions#user-defined-memgraph-magic-functions) which will allow you to sort the items correctly
- maybe a quick fix is to order on the client/application side (I'm aware of all the problems that might produce, large transferred data volume, and slow queries), but maybe it's a quick solution for you.

There is [a related GitHub issue](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/307). Please contribute with more details or follow the discussion. At some point, we'll add native capability :) Also, we are looking for contributors!