# How to compare string with Latin characters to same string with English characters in IICS?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, iics, iics-di

For example, how to successfully compare "André" and "Andre"?

I tried some `Reg_replace` options without any success.

Comment: Please specify what programming language are you using.

Comment: This is Informatica cloud. “Reg_replace” is an expression function in Informatica cloud.

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by successfully compare? The two strings you’ve provided are different and you appear to be saying that an e with an accent and an e without an accent are the same, but on what basis are you defining them as the same?

Comment: I have 2 tables with names. One of them has accents and other one was created as part of a migration and most of the names dropped the accents. The comparison strategy that we defined is Accent insensitive. So “André” should be match for “Andre”

Comment: There is no such thing as “accent insensitive” - at least as far as how computers represent characters. The e and the é are completely different characters (have a look at an ascii table) - so you would need to define which characters you consider to be identical and then explicitly code those business rules into your SQL - possibly via regex or some similar mechanism

Comment: You can do accent insensitive comparisons in SQL server with collate and the correct collation name. For example “COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI” changes Latin char to Case Insensitive and Accent insensitive English char. We also have Transliterator in Java that can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box function available in IICS. Try using Java transformation to remove the diacritics. Here's [one SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322174/2834065) I've found that should provide some help.

Note there may be some more up to date libraries now.

Comment: I think this is the closest to a solution for this. As always thank you Maciejg