# Java - from 'special' chars to its 'base'

Tags: java, string, char

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Converting Symbols, Accent Letters to English Alphabet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet)
>   [ń ǹ ň ñ ṅ ņ ṇ ṋ ṉ ̈ ɲ ƞ ᶇ ɳ ȵ --> n or Remove diacritical marks from unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-char)

Hi,

is there a way (java method or lib) to replace all special chars to their base?

something like this:

```
String result = magicalMethod("łéàç");
assertEquals(result, "leac");
```

thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-char