# icu4j cyrillic to latin

Tags: java, icu, transliteration

I'm trying to get Cyrillic words to be in latin so I can have them in urls. I use [icu4j](http://site.icu-project.org/) transliterator, but it still gives weird characters like this: **Vilʹândimaa**. It should be more like **viljandimaa**. When I copy that url these letters turn to %.. something useless.

Does anybody know how to get Cyrillic to a-z with icu4j?

**UPDATE**

Can't answer myself already but found this question that was very helpful: [Converting Symbols, Accent Letters to English Alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Modify your [identifier](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) to do what you want. You can strip unwanted characters using a regular expression with the `Remove` transform.

For example, consider the string *"'Eé математика"*:

```
"'E\u00E9 \u043c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430"
```

The identifier `"Any-Latin; NFD; [^\\p{Alnum}] Remove"` will transliterate to Latin (which may still include accents), decompose accented characters into the letter and diacritics and remove anything that isn't an alphanumeric. The resultant string is *"Eematematika"*.

You can read more on the identifiers under [General Transforms](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) on the ICU website.

---

Example:

```
//import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;
String greek
       = "'E\u00E9 \u043c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430";
String id = "Any-Latin; NFD; [^\\p{Alnum}] Remove";
String latin = Transliterator.getInstance(id)
                             .transform(greek);
System.out.println(latin);
```

*Tested against ICU4J 49.1.*

Comment: Thanks McDowell - could you give a really quick example?

Comment: @Nicholas Tolley Cottrell - Example added.

Comment: Thanks again McDowell - I ended up using "Any-Latin; NFD" since I wanted to preserve spaces.

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell - That will leave the diacritics intact (accents on Latin letters.) The point of the NFD transform is to separate accents and letters into two consecutive code points. If you want to preserve spaces, modify the regular expression in the `Remove` transformation.

Comment: Another, perhaps cleaner, take would be to use `Any-Latin; Lower; Latin-ASCII` instead of NFD with manual filtering — that converts to ASCII-only as much as possible explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633355/Показать-правильный-пример-транслитерации-на-java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633355/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java)

Add denepdency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>63.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And transliterate:

```
var CYRILLIC_TO_LATIN = "Latin-Russian/BGN"
// var CYRILLIC_TO_LATIN = "Russian-Latin/BGN"
Transliterator toLatinTrans = Transliterator.getInstance(CYRILLIC_TO_LATIN);
String result = toLatinTrans.transliterate(st);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have no idea about icu4j, but [in the Unicode table Cyrillic takes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_%28Unicode_block%29) only a small range. Instead of relaying onto third-party libraries with unclear workings, I'd define a transliteration sequence for each Cyrillic symbol and did the translation myself.

P.S. What language word "viljandimaa" comes from? Doesn't sound like Cyrillic to me...

Comment: Thanks for answering. Its estonian locations is russian.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer without any dependency!**

```
System.out.println(TransliterationUtil.transliterate("Съешь этих мягких французских булок"));
```

Stdout: `Sesh etih mjagkih frantsuzskih bulok`

```
public class TransliterationUtil {

    private TransliterationUtil() {
    }

    private static final Map<Character, String> cyrToLatMap;
    static {
        cyrToLatMap = new HashMap<>();
        cyrToLatMap.put(' ', " ");
        cyrToLatMap.put('а', "a");
        cyrToLatMap.put('б', "b");
        cyrToLatMap.put('в', "v");
        cyrToLatMap.put('г', "g");
        cyrToLatMap.put('д', "d");
        cyrToLatMap.put('е', "e");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ё', "e");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ж', "zh");
        cyrToLatMap.put('з', "z");
        cyrToLatMap.put('и', "i");
        cyrToLatMap.put('й', "y");
        cyrToLatMap.put('к', "k");
        cyrToLatMap.put('л', "l");
        cyrToLatMap.put('м', "m");
        cyrToLatMap.put('н', "n");
        cyrToLatMap.put('о', "o");
        cyrToLatMap.put('п', "p");
        cyrToLatMap.put('р', "r");
        cyrToLatMap.put('с', "s");
        cyrToLatMap.put('т', "t");
        cyrToLatMap.put('у', "u");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ф', "f");
        cyrToLatMap.put('х', "h");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ц', "ts");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ч', "ch");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ш', "sh");
        cyrToLatMap.put('щ', "sch");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ъ', "");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ы', "i");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ь', "");
        cyrToLatMap.put('э', "e");
        cyrToLatMap.put('ю', "ju");
        cyrToLatMap.put('я', "ja");
        cyrToLatMap.put('А', "A");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Б', "B");
        cyrToLatMap.put('В', "V");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Г', "G");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Д', "D");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Е', "E");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ё', "E");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ж', "Zh");
        cyrToLatMap.put('З', "Z");
        cyrToLatMap.put('И', "I");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Й', "Y");
        cyrToLatMap.put('К', "K");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Л', "L");
        cyrToLatMap.put('М', "M");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Н', "N");
        cyrToLatMap.put('О', "O");
        cyrToLatMap.put('П', "P");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Р', "R");
        cyrToLatMap.put('С', "S");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Т', "T");
        cyrToLatMap.put('У', "U");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ф', "F");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Х', "H");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ц', "Ts");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ч', "Ch");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ш', "Sh");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Щ', "Sch");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ъ', "");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ы', "I");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ь', "");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Э', "E");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Ю', "Ju");
        cyrToLatMap.put('Я', "Ja");
    }

    public static String transliterate(String message){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (var ch : message.toCharArray()) {
            builder.append(cyrToLatMap.getOrDefault(ch,"?"));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```