# How to make Solr spellchecker to correct both Latin and Cyrillic words?

Tags: solr

I allow users to type Russian words in Latin letters. If user misspells Russian word in Latin letters, I want Solr spellchecker to suggest correct word in Cyrillic (Russian words in the index is in Cyrillic). However, if user misspells not a Russian word (for example a brand name), it should be corrected in Latin letters (not russian words in the index is in Latin).

For example, `tilevizor smasung` should be fixed to `телевизор samsung`

Now I'm using the following configuration:

```
<fieldType name="spell_ru" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ICUTransformFilterFactory" id="Any-Cyrillic; NFD; [^\p{Alnum}] Remove" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="256" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

It converts query to Cyrillic letters, so Russian words correction works. But Latin doesn't. (`tilevizor` to `телевизор` works, but `smasung` to `samsung` doesn't).

Any ideas, how can I make spellchecker to correct both Cyrillic and Latin words?

Comment: What is your actual spellchecker configuration. The above is only the field definition.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that solution, that could help here is Beider-Morse Phonetic Matching (BMPM)

> Beider-Morse Phonetic Matching (BMPM) is a "soundalike" tool that lets
>   you search using a new phonetic matching system.

So, for example words 'tilevizor' and 'телевизор' will sound a like and we will get a match. Something that could be tuned is the algorithm for phonetic matching. Solr is [supporting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-PhoneticFilter) a lot of them and I'm not sure which one will perform better : DoubleMetaphone, Metaphone, Soundex, RefinedSoundex, Caverphone (v2.0), ColognePhonetic, or Nysiis.

Also, I would like to update `solr.ICUTransformFilterFactory` with `id="Russian-Latin/BGN"`, which do a much better job converting Russian symbols to Latin ones.

```
    <fieldType name="spell_ru" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ICUTransformFilterFactory" id="Russian-Latin/BGN"/>
            <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Caverphone"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ICUTransformFilterFactory" id="Russian-Latin/BGN"/>
            <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Caverphone"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

The fieldType above do the trick in a lot of cases, e.g

```
q=title:tilevizor
SolrDocument{title=телевизор samsung, _version_=1583123812650582016}
SolrDocument{title=televizor самсунг, _version_=1583123812667359232}

q=title:тилевизор
SolrDocument{title=телевизор samsung, _version_=1583123812650582016}
SolrDocument{title=televizor самсунг, _version_=1583123812667359232}

q=title:smasung
SolrDocument{title=телевизор samsung, _version_=1583123812650582016}
SolrDocument{title=televizor самсунг, _version_=1583123812667359232}
SolrDocument{title=гэлакси samsung, _version_=1583123812684136448}
SolrDocument{title=galaxy самсунг, _version_=1583123812684136449}
```

I've created the following test class [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene6/src/main/scala/PhoneticSpellchecking.scala), feel free to play with this one.