# Remove letter accents from a given text

Tags: c, character-encoding, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but is there a "painless" way to replace the accented letters in a given text with their unaccented counterparts? I can only use the standard ANSI C libraries/headers, so my hands are tied. What I've tried so far:

```
unsigned char currentChar;

(...)

if (currentChar == 'à') { 
    currentChar = 'a'; 
}
else if (currentChar == 'è' || currentChar == 'é') {
    currentChar = 'e'; 
}
else if (...)
```

However, this doesn't work. Detecting accented vowels with their extended ASCII value isn't an option, either, as I've noticed that it changes depending upon the system locale.

Any hints/suggestions?

(update)

Thanks for the answers, but I'm not really asking for the best approach for this problem - I'll think about it later. I'm simply asking for a way to detect the accented vowels, as the code above simply ignores them.

(update #2)

Okay. Let me clarify:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char vowels[6] = {'à','è','é','ì','ò','ù'};
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        switch (vowels[i]) {
            case 'à': vowels[i] = 'a'; break;
            case 'è': vowels[i] = 'e'; break;
            case 'é': vowels[i] = 'e'; break;
            case 'ì': vowels[i] = 'i'; break;
            case 'ò': vowels[i] = 'o'; break;
            case 'ù': vowels[i] = 'u'; break;
        }
     }
     printf("\n");
     for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         printf("%c",vowels[i]);
     }
     printf("\n");
     return 0;
}
```

This code still prints "àèéìòù" as its output. This is my problem. I appreciate the answers, however it's pointless to tell me to implement a conversion map, or a switch/case structure. I'll think about it *later*.

Comment: While maybe not a solution to your problem, I would at least use `switch` instead of lot's of `if...else if` statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991207/efficently-replacement-of-all-unsupported-chars-in-a-string/12991244#12991244

Comment: What is ANSI C for you? AFAIK, ANSI is in sync with the ISO standards committee about the revisions of C, with the current revision being C11. Do you mean that or C89?

Comment: They're called **diacritical marks**. May help you search.

Comment: Nancy, how are you compiling?  When I compile your code I get many ` warning: multi-character character constant` - ie. your accented characters are not single chars

Comment: @WilliamMorris: good observation, the source code encoding is probably UTF-8 but the compiler doesn't support that and sees the characters as multi-byte "character" constants (which don't compare equal to characters).

Answer (score 3):

The accented characters are likely part of the UTF-8 character set, or some other encoding. Your program is using the `char` type, which usually uses the [ASCII character set](http://www.asciitable.com/).

In the ASCII character set, each character is represented by a single byte. This character set does not include the accent character.

Other encodings do include the character, but it is probably not represented by a single byte and so cannot be processed by your code. The solution to this is usually to use wide characters.

What you will need are [wide characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287213/what-is-a-wide-character-string-in-c-language) may has more general explanation.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373463/handling-special-characters-in-c-utf-8-encoding) may provide a solution for your case.

This code seems to do what you would like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!f)
        return 1;

    for (wchar_t c; (c = fgetwc(f)) != WEOF;){
        switch (c) {
            case L'à': c=L'a'; break;
            case L'è': c=L'e';break;
            case L'é': c=L'e';break;
            case L'ì': c=L'i';break;
            case L'ò': c=L'o';break;
            case L'ù': c=L'u';break;
            default:    break;
        }
        wprintf(L"%lc", c);
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NancyB., I've posted a block of code that seems to do what you would like.

Comment: And just made a quick correction so that it reads `wprintf(L"%c", c);`. I've tested and it works for me.

Comment: overflow with that method

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier way, some existing functionality that I haven't heard of, but as far as structure, this is how I'd approach it:

Build a table of character conversions consisting of the accent character and the resulting character. Then build a simple loop to scan the table for each character, and if found, make the change.

Comment: Okay, but the problem I've encountered is - the accented vowels simply aren't recognized. I know that isalpha() doesn't handle them, so I've implemented some explicit checks, but they don't seem to be able to detect the vowels themselves.

Comment: My suggested structure does not require `isalpha()` or any other CRT code. Please read my suggestion again and let me know if there are parts you do not understand.

Comment: @NancyB.: yeah, `is*()` from `ctype.h` doesn't handle them.. you can want to look at `wchar.h' routines.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
if ( currentChar == (unsigned char)('è'))...
```

your approach should work given your constraint of only using std c libraries I don't see how you otherwise pull it off.

Comment: This might work, but only because the accented chars are composed of two bytes and the cast is telling the compiler to use one of these bytes). So on my system, 'à' is represented by 0xC3 and 0xA0, 'è' is 0xC3, 0xA8 etc. The cast is telling the `if` to look only at the value 0xA8.   Also, the solution will likely fail on a machine with the opposite endianness.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this one:

```
char p_RemoveAccent(char C)
{
    #define ACCENT_CHARS    "ÁÀÃÂÇáàãâçÉÊéêÍíÑÓÔÕñóôõÚÜúü"
    #define UNACCENT_CHARS  "AAAACaaaacEEeeIiNOOOnoooUUuu"

    const char *p_Char = memchr(ACCENT_CHARS, C, sizeof(ACCENT_CHARS));

    return (p_Char ? UNACCENT_CHARS[(p_Char - ACCENT_CHARS)] : C);
}
```

Comment: Nice but OP clearly stated ".. I'm not really asking for the best approach for this problem - I'll think about it later. I'm simply asking for a way to **detect** the accented vowels .."  -- OPs source encoding is hiding them.

Comment: Doesn't work because accented chars are longer than 1 byte so `UNACCENT_CHARS[(p_Char - ACCENT_CHARS)]` will hit the wrong unaccented char