# Replace all accented vowels using ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, replace

Is there any way to dynamically replace accented characters such as the following?

```
requesón => requeson
```

What I mean is that every accented (or whatever) character would be replaced with the normal one.

Is this possible using ColdFusion?

Comment: I know that you could use a regular expression to _remove_ the special characters but not sure about replacing.  That would mean you will need some sort of mapping for each character and it's replacement.  Are you dealing with a limited number of characters that you know, or are you wanting to replace any special character that is encountered?

Comment: I would need to replace every special character found, but I think that this is going to be difficult. So I already think in the option of replace know special caracters.

Comment: It would be also nice to have some regex which select, for example, "e" and all its special characters. Then I could replace them with the normal one.

Comment: What is the actual task you are trying to solve? (i.e. why do you [think you] need to remove accents?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix accented characters through java text normalization and a regex. There is a function on cflib that does this already:

From: http://cflib.org/udf/deAccent

```
function deAccent(str){
    //based on the approach found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1215117/894061
    var Normalizer = createObject("java","java.text.Normalizer");
    var NormalizerForm = createObject("java","java.text.Normalizer$Form");
    var normalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, createObject("java","java.text.Normalizer$Form").NFD);
    var pattern = createObject("java","java.util.regex.Pattern").compile("\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(normalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```

Comment: The last two lines of that function can be merged into one: `return normalizedString.replaceAll("\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+","");`

Comment: Looking into what NFD form changes - there's a spec here: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-23.html#Decomposition - it doesn't replace `ß` for example, but if I try searching for that in the document, but stupid Chrome is searching for `ss` - which appears over a hundred times. :/