# How to compare strings with special characters like ü, ć, š etc?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have some text imported from sqlite database and then I set that text to some button. Now, I have some text like München, or Stanković, or Kazalište. You get the point. User has to guess the right answer and I solved the issue when user insert lowercase word, and my word is with first letter capital. I just convert my word and his entered word to uppercase. But how to accept the answer even if user enter Munchen, or Stankovic or Kazaliste, without those special letters that I have in my database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3322174/106261

Comment: This looks very similiar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1453171/1343161).

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet

Answer (score 0):

Try using collator.

[Performing Locale-Independent Comparisons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html)

> Collation rules define the sort sequence of strings. These rules vary
>   with locale, because various natural languages sort words differently.
>   You can use the predefined collation rules provided by the Collator
>   class to sort strings in a locale-independent manner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to explicitly replace all the special characters with the acceptable characters.  So, ü -> u and so on.  Just as you have done by using toUpperCase which substitutes u with U.

Answer (score 0):

```
String expression ="š|ć|ü";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
if (matcher.matches()) 
{
//your code
}
```

Comment: you can use this concept also [a-zA-Z]