# Compare strings ignoring accented characters

Tags: java, string, compare, accent-insensitive

I would like to know if there is a method that compares 2 strings and ignores the accents making "noção" equal to "nocao".
it would be something like string1.methodCompareIgnoreAccent(string2);

Comment: Have you looked at [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)?

Comment: You can also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet.

Comment: I have written a class for searching trough arabic texts by ignoring diacritic (NOT removing them). maybe you can get the idea or use it in some way.
 https://gist.github.com/mehdok/e6cd1dfccab0c75ac7a9536c6afac8ff

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use java Collators for comparing the tests ignoring the accent **and case**, see a simple example:

```
import java.text.Collator;

/**
 * @author Kennedy
 */
public class SimpleTest
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String a = "nocao";
    String b = "noção";

    final Collator instance = Collator.getInstance();

    // This strategy mean it'll ignore the accents and the case
    instance.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);

    // Will print 0 because its EQUAL
    System.out.println(instance.compare(a, b));
  }
}
```

Documentation: [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html)

**Be aware that this collator also ignores differences in case**, i.e. it also treats `"NOCAO"` as equal to `"noção"`. To create a collator that ignores accent differences but distingishes case, you might be able to use a [RuleBasedCollator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html)

Do not confuse `Collator.setStrength()` with `Collator.setDecomposition()`. The `Collator` constants `PRIMARY`, `SECONDARY`, `TERTIARY` and `IDENTICAL` must only be used with `setStrength()`, while the constants `NO_DECOMPOSITION`, `CANONICAL_DECOMPOSITION` and `FULL_DECOMPOSITION` must only be used with `setDecomposition()`. (A previous version of this code mixed this up and only worked because `NO_DECOMPOSITION` and `PRIMARY` happen to have the [same integer value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.text.Collator.IDENTICAL).)

Comment: thank you. Didn't know about Collator

Comment: this doesn't work, it won't print 0. Sometimes it prints -1 other times 1

Comment: It works, get the code before the weston edited.

Comment: your first answer worked. Now I want to edit the answer so that it shows your answer, do you now how I can do it?

Comment: did it! you can accept this asnwer again if you want too.

Answer (score 9):

There is no built in method to do this, so you have to build your own:

A part of this is solution is from [here](http://drillio.com/en/software/java/remove-accent-diacritic/) : 
This first splits all accented characters into their deAccented counterparts followed by their combining diacritics. Then you simply remove all combining diacritics.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215117/4095834

And then your equals method will look like this:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // Code omitted
    if (yourField.equals(removeAccents(anotherField))) {
        return true;
    }
}

public static String removeAccents(String text) {
    return text == null ? null : Normalizer.normalize(text, Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```