# Search a string for a substring accents-insensitive

Tags: android, localization

I am Greek.
When I search in my Contacts with substring `"αυλ"`, all of these contacts match: `"Παύλος"`, `"Παυλίνα"`, `"Αυλός"`.

So, Android match in letter "α" both letters "α" and "ά".

Is there an API for this feature, or I must code this the hard way?
e.g.: `string.replaceAll("ά", "α").replaceAll("έ", "ε").replaceAll(......)`
which is not so multilingual approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet) seems to be along the lines of what you want.

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public String deAccent(String str) {
    String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```

In recent versions of Java, some Unicode support was added with `\p{Script=Greek}`, `\p{sc=Greek}`, `\p{IsGreek}`, and `\p{Greek}`. You'll probably want to look into using these.